# AOP Logging understanding

Tags: c#, design-patterns, aop

I have been working out how I can use Aspect Oriented Programming and have followed [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp-using-dispatchproxy/) as a start. I have got this working here so I have before and after method call logging. I then wanted to use that logger to do the rest of the logging we would normally do in and around the object in question. All I had to do for it to work was to change the last line of SetParameters from:

```
 _loggingScheduler = loggingScheduler ?? TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

to

```
_loggingScheduler = loggingScheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Current;
```

Not sure why that worked for me but it does. Then I wanted to be able to use that Aspect/Decoration to do the rest of the logging we would require. So I added a Log Method to the aspect and used it accordingly:

```
public void Log(string level, string msg)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{level} {DateTime.Now.ToString("s")} {msg}");
}
```

So just console logging for now. I used that method like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var calculator = LoggingAdvice<ICalculator>.Create(
                              new Calculator(),
                              s => Console.WriteLine("Info: " + s),
                              s => Console.WriteLine("Error: " + s),
                              o => o?.ToString());

    var addition = calculator.Add(2, 2);
    ((LoggingAdvice<ICalculator>)calculator).Log("Info", $"The result of Add was {addition}");

    var subtraction = calculator.Subtract(10, 4);
    ((LoggingAdvice<ICalculator>)calculator).Log("Info", $"The result of Subtract was {subtraction}");



    Console.WriteLine($"Results: Add - {addition}, subtract - {subtraction}");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Which is, realistically, just a duplication of the `LogAfter()` functionality. What I thought I could achieve with this is to use the aspect for all of the logging I wanted which is:

- Before and after method calls (tick)
- Use it to log around the object (tick)
- Log inside the Calculator (completely stuck on)

Now I am starting to circle round on myself and my understanding of what I am doing here is waning.

So my questions are:

- What am i doing here - AOP, Decorator or Proxy pattern (probably a mix)
- Can I use the aspect inside the decorated object
- Do I still have to DI a logger into my classes for internal logging
- How much of a violation is the Calculator cast

So basically I am being a little greedy here and want to use the aspect I have created to do all of my logging. Is this possible?

Comment: That's not AOP code, and that's not AOP. The article is trying to copy Java concepts into .NET and getting quite confused in the process. `AOP` means adding aspects to some component. How is that achieved? There are *many* ways. Injecting them with a DI container is one way, and that's the most common way of injecting logging in .Net, eg in an ASP.NET MVC controller or action. The *specifics* never appear in the controller itself. Another way is to wrap operations in filters that implement those aspects. Just like MVC filters and .NET Core middleware

Comment: What that article does is implement a proxy while saying that proxies are bad. The end result *is* bad, and quite a bit more complex than the examples it links to. There's a reason proxies like that aren't used in .NET. They harm performance, make debugging a *lot* harder, are very complex to write correctly. There's a reason PostSharp, a paid AOP framework, isn't free and no-one else produced a free/OSS version

Comment: Frameworks and .NET itself have changed a *lot* since the late 00s when AOP was introduced. Many things that were new AOP concepts have become built-in features or conventions. Injecting code into a component, what proxies try to do, is generally frowned upon because it makes debugging hard and you never really know what's getting called. Filter pipelines are provided by most MVC or MVC like frameworks. DI makes creating factories that wrap behaviour easy.

Comment: Check for example [HttpClientFactory and Polly](Think [HttpClientFactory and Polly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). A few lines add retries and recovery policies to any HttpClient instance generated from that factory, without code injection or proxies.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is what I suspected. So the DI approach can be considered AOP? Frankly I was struggling to see an advantage over the usual DI approach I would take.

Comment: AOP is a concept, just like OOP. There's stuff (aspects, cross-cutting concerns, services, whatevers) that are needed by many components but don't belong in any of them. Instead of trying to stuff them in every component, you create them separately and use/call/add them when necessary (weaving). There are a *lot* of ways to implement those aspects and a lot of ways to inject/weave them in code. In the early days injecting them into existing code seemed like a good idea. Nowadays though, many mechanisms like DI, pipeline composition have become standard

Comment: DI is a *tool* that can make working in an AOP way easier, not *the* tool. HttpClientFactory and Polly for example use that *and* custom handlers, *and* their own implementations combined. .NET Core middleware creates pipelines, with DI making the job a bit easier. Logging though is typically implemented as an injected interface, unless you want per-request logging when it's used in a filter/middleware.